Jenkins - SF cli cannot seem to access SF_ACCESS_TOKEN in the environment
I am using sf org login access-token --instance-url https://myorg.my.salesforce.com --no-prompt to login to a Salesforce Org. On Jenkins, I am setting the SF_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable. However, when the command, runs I get an error like shown below
+ npx sf org login access-token --no-prompt --instance-url https://myorg.my.salesforce.com --alias default-org
node:os:365
    throw new ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR(ctx);
          ^

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_get_passwd returned ENOENT (no such file or directory)
    at userInfo (node:os:365:11)
    at Config._shell (/<JenkinsWorkspace>/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/config.js:587:67)
    at Config.load (/<JenkinsWorkspace>/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/config.js:309:27)
    at async Config.load (/<JenkinsWorkspace>/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/config.js:167:9)
    at async Module.run (file:///<JenkinsWorkspace>/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/dist/cli.js:84:20)
    at async file:///<JenkinsWorkspace>/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/bin/run.js:15:1 {
  code: 'ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR',
  info: {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    message: 'no such file or directory',
    syscall: 'uv_os_get_passwd'
  },
  errno: [Getter/Setter],
  syscall: [Getter/Setter]
}

I have masked the JenkinsWorkspace. Salesforce CLI is installed locally within my repo.
Here is my pipeline with the relevant stage.
...
stage('Deploy') {
            environment {
                SF_ACCESS_TOKEN = "$SfToken"
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                    npx sf org login access-token --no-prompt --instance-url ${SfInstanceUrl} --alias default-org
                    """

                    sh 'npx sf project deploy start --source-dir force-app --concise --target-org default-org'
                }
            }
        }
...

